# need to get data in array format usig jquery/ajax in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

while submitting a form I am getting the result in ..

```
name1=abhishekacad=test
```

but i need to get data in array format.

```
$('button[type="submit"]').on('click',function(e)
{
   e.preventDefault();
   var submit_value = $(this).val();
   var acad_title = $("#acad_title option:selected").text(); 
   var name_suffix = $("#name_suffix").val();
   var dataString = 'name1='+ name_suffix + 'acad=' +acad_title ;

   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       data: dataString,
       async: false,
       url: "test.php",
    })
```

there might be syntax error.

I am very new to stackoverflow please ignore if it's not well formatted, sorry and thaks.

Comment: don't use `async: false` it blocks the UI and is bad practice

Answer (score 1):

if you want to post the data of the form use this:

```
$('button[type="submit"]').on('click',function(e)
{
   e.preventDefault();

   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       data: $(this).serialize(),
       async: false,
       url: "test.php"
    });
}
```

Read more [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)
You'll have to set the form field names correctly for this one like

```
<input type="text" name="name1" />
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works, but now if I have 20 field then will go this way as you suggested

Comment: +1 however you are missing `acad_title` from OP ?  I would just delete the first code block.

Comment: how can i get if i have more than 20 field will go that way only i.e.

Comment: @user3858643 I updated the answer. Note that you will have to set the form names right for this one.

Comment: <pre>Array
(
)  getting blank aray :(

Comment: Sorry? I cant follow you. Where did you try this?

Comment: when url hit the function I just tried $data = $_POST; echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); i.e. in php

Comment: For data assignment use `$(this).closest('form').serialize()` instead of just `$(this).serialize()`.

Comment: suppose I have 50 fields on form and in one div I have 10 field then that div contain one sumbit button and at the end of the form also hav submit button. but when I click div submit button i want field of that div only

Comment: Then you should use the manual method you mentioned and be very careful with the parameters name-value pairs and the ambersand between  pairs. Also sth like `$('#divId :input').serialize();` or `$('#divId :input').serializeArray();` would do the job for you.

Comment: ok can we send two datastring in $.ajax data:dataString, between I am trying, but I get answer then it will be good :)

Comment: As it sound to me you should register two seperate event handlers, one for the div submit and one for the form.

Answer (score 0):

Your datastring is not passed correctly at the very moment because of a missing ambersand. If you don't want to pass your parameters values manually you could take advantage of jQuery's `serialize()` method to produce a result like:

```
  "name1=value1&name2=value2"
```

doing so:

```
$('button[type="submit"]').on('click',function(e)
{
   e.preventDefault();
   var submit_value = $(this).val(), 
       dataString   = $(this).closest('form').serialize();

   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       data: dataString,
       async: false,
       url: "test.php"
    });
}
```

This collects all input fields values. Of course only the fields that you have a declared name attribute are taken into account. Of course you have to match the input fields names with the parameters php awaits for. If not your ajax call is going to fail.

Now if you want to pass an array you could use `serializeArray()` that returns a format like so:

```
[
  {
    name: "a",
    value: "1"
  },
  {
    name: "b",
    value: "2"
  }
]
```

Also consider using

```
$('form').on('submit',function(e){});
```

so that your code can run after submit button is clicked or also after `enter` or `return` keys are pressed.